# Applying real-time filter to HDMI input with HDMI output?

Tags: hdmi

**TL;DR: Is it possible to use a Raspberry Pi (or similar) to act as a live "filter" for a HDMI signal?**

My wife has bad vertigo and hasn't been able to watch live TV for a while now.
A while back, I realised that she could watch movies/TV shows if I converted them to be more like a "slideshow", by reducing the frame rate to ~2.5 secs (any faster and the motion is too much), but leaving the audio untouched. I have a FFMPEG script that does this easily, but it's only good for downloaded video files.

For a sample of what I mean - here's a clip of a well-known video after said processing (https://youtu.be/ihmHYvIYFvs)

What I'd ideally like is to have a device (RPi/other) which has source HDMI coming in, the box locking the video framerate, then sending HDMI output on another port.
Then if I can enable/disable the processing part (e.g. let the signal passthrough untouched when disabled), then I could turn it on when my wife is watching TV, but turn it off when I want to watch it unaffected.

Does anyone know if a custom project like this would be possible? (I'm aware HDMI is pretty locked down for these kinds of things)

Failing that - if an off-the-shelf product that has this capability (e.g. a capture card/box that has a frame-limiter or something) then that could be something worth looking into.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Pi lacks a HDMI input (indeed most computers don't have this capacity). You may be able to find a HDMI capture device, but this becomes a shopping question.